# VBScript "open all workbooks" Error Handling

Tags: error-handling, vbscript

My `VBScript` opens all "xlsm" files in a folder, runs `VBA` code "Slim" and closes the workbook  (one-by-one). It works fine, but I struggle with error handling. If the script tries to open a workbook currently open by someone else, I end up with error popup `Someone else is working in /path + wb-name/ right now. Please try again later.` and the loop pauses up until `OK` is clicked on the warning message. Looks like it will open the workbook no problem, but ends up with an error at the end since the VBA code saves a new file and tries to delete the old one. Hence, I'll end up with a new file and non-deleted old one on top of the error message.

While clearly not the ideal solution, quitting the whole loop in this scenario would also be better than waiting for the OK to be clicked, since VBScript is automated to launch.

I'd need to build an error handling for this scenario, so that already opened file would just be skipped and the loop would continue uninterrupted. Unfortunately, `DisplayAlerts = False` good ol' `On Error Resume Next` won't do it here.

If possible in a reasonable way, I'd like to solve this through VBScript and not adjust the VBA code.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

On Error Resume Next
xl.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("G:\Archive").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsm" Then
    
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)
    
    xl.Run "Slim"    
    wb.Close

  End If

Next

xl.Quit

Set fso = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
```

Tried different scenarios, haven't cracked it so far. Latest option was this, but didn't help (is there a different way of checking if the workbook is currently read-only)?

```
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("G:\Archive").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsm" Then
    
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(f.Path) 
    
    If NOT wb.ReadOnly Then

    xl.Run "Slim"
    wb.Close

    Else

    wb.Close

    End If
        
  End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an excel file is open, opening it again is blocked. Renaming the file is also blocked, but a failed rename does not show a message box with `resume next`

Try this code. It tries to rename the file first. If the rename succeeds, it renames back then runs the macro. If rename fails, it skips the file.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xl  = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

On Error Resume Next
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("D:\MikeStuff\StackOverflow\ExcelCheckOpen").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "xlsm" Then
    xpath = f.Path  ' file path lost after rename
    fso.MoveFile xpath, xpath & ".txt"  ' will fail if file locked by excel
    if fso.FileExists(xpath & ".txt") Then ' rename worked, file not locked
        fso.MoveFile xpath & ".txt", xpath  ' rename back
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(xpath)
        xl.Run "Slim"    
        wb.Close
    End If
  End If
Next

xl.Quit

Set fso = Nothing
Set xl = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Looks like a nice way to do that. I think the latter part of the code needs some adjustment though.

Firstly I think one End If is missing for the nested IF statement (will report "next unexpected" error otherwise). But there's something more that I don't crack right away. If one End If is added after wb.Close, the code will run, but it will just end up with renamed files, e.g looks like the rename-back + Workbook Open + xl.Run won't run (though the currently open file is not renamed - so the primary IF-check works).

Comment: Sorry - Typo on my part. `End If` added. For the other issue - If the rename succeeds, it should rename the file back to the original name. Are you seeing duplicate files with different names?

Comment: Nope, the .txt extension remains, e.g. no duplicates either. Pretty sure the nested IF is not launched at all - it will pretty much run in the blink of an eye, so doesn't look a workbook open is even attampted.

Added a message box WScript.Echo to the end to mark the end of script. This is also shown no problem, so the FOR EACH cycle is passed through.

Comment: Another typo. Should be `f.Path`. Please retry.

Comment: Nope, still acts the same - everything is renamed to .txt (except the open file)

Comment: Might it still be a problem with IF-clause? Does it need to be a nested double IF and 
doesn't work with ELSE (though my attempt produced the same results)?

Comment: Checking...  Looks like issue with file object

Comment: Got it (I think). Please retry.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't immediately test again. But now it works like a charm. Big thanks!

Comment: Interestingly though the code has become a lot slower compared to the original. A few hundred xlsb files in the folder and just a few xlsm-s. It took a few minutes to work through a few xlsm-s while before it might have taken, maybe, 10-15 seconds. But I guess it's not a fundamental issue. Have to give it another try later on. In a test folder with 5-6 xlsm files and nothing else, it ran very smoothly.